# How to organize a fallback system for older GPUs in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, c++, compatibility

I don't want to make this question too broad or opinion based, but I really need some help about good practices.

The scenario:

I created a particle engine with functions which require at least OpenGL 4.3. But some GPUs don't support this version, so I want to try to implement a fallback system for it.

But it's not only the particle system. There are many features in 3D engines that can't be simply replaced by a different function name. Some features need different logic behind them and it can go quite complex.

What are the best practices to manage fallback rendering in OpenGL?

Comment: Do you use any important GL 4 features? Or you just use bind-less state changing functions? If so I'd say just use lowest GL version you can (usually it is 3 if you need framebuffers and 2 if you don't). Instead of creating *two* systems: default and fallback, you can just create one on the old GL. The question is: do you really need those extra bits of performance on new videocards at the cost of writing and debugging double amount of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid option is: Don't do a fallback.

If you look at the system requirements for released games, even indie games, you'll see that they invariably set a minimum and don't support anything below that.  These games don't have fallbacks.

Wanting to run on all hardware is an unrealistic objective.  It's a truth that you're going to come across hardware that just won't run your game, and implementing fallbacks involves more than just features.  Does the older GPU have enough video memory for your textures?  If not you'll need to provide lower res alternate texture sets.  Is it fast enough to process your geometry?  If not you'll need to provide lower detail meshes.  Can it handle your lighting, your shading, the number of blend passes you do, your post processing?  Any of these can choke an older GPU even if you limit yourself to GL 2.1 features.

That's why coding fallbacks for older or weaker hardware might not actually be what you want.  You could easily risk doubling your development time and creating complex, fragile code, and for what?  An extra few percent can run your game.  Only you can decide if that's a tradeoff you want; I suggest it may not be.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, your fallback system is very easy to do because you are the one creating every single shader and feeding it to the card.

When you initialize OpenGL in SDL for example, you have to pass in the version in major and minor form. If you don't get an error, it worked. If if fails, try again with the next lowest supported version. Save this information on startup you will need it later.

Then when you create the shaders to send to the card, generate the proper shader programs based on these versions. How you do that exactly is up to you. You can have different methods for each version, or else have separate shader files, or else have a section of the shader that gets a different section based on how different it is. It all depends on the situation.

If you would generate compute shaders in 4.3 for one method and not the other, then this should still apply fine. Just alter your program shader object that contains your shader info to also hold compute shaders...and don't use a compute shader for the lower versions.

You don't need a fancy 'shader manager' or anything like that. You should be able to have the shader program object be more or less self contained.